# Installing video card with on-board VGA output fried

Tags: video, graphics-card, desktop

I have a desktop system, around 7 years old. I was using it until last month without any problem. After a short circuit in my power extension board my desktop's video output has stopped working, along with the attached tuner card.

I have tried many things without success, but I have figured out that the CPU and other things are working fine. Only the display has stopped working.

Is there a way I can install a new graphics card, a very basic one to get the display back?

I have heard that any system with onboard graphics would by default use the onboard graphics unless manually switched to external video card.

Currently I am able to do nothing, not even BIOS can be accessed as there is no display output.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without knowing exactly what has been damaged and if the computer even can run properly with that damage provided you don't use the functions that the damaged components handle. Personally, I would be very very careful since damaged components may not work properly and in a worst case scenario a heat buildup could result in a fire...

But, put in a very cheap gfx card and give it a whirl, there is always a chance that it could indeed work. By default the integrated graphics is disabled when you have an external graphics card. However, the damage may prevent this from happening.

Edit: I re-read the topic now and it does infact say OUTPUT fried. So if its just the actual port that's not working and its no shorting, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I would try this. I didn't realise I had asked this question, since then the desktop is lying broken.